# Static Tooltip below UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, static, uinavigationcontroller, tooltip

In my application, I have an `UITableViewController` inside an `UINavigationController` in storyboard. What I am trying to do is to have a static tooltip (`UIImageView` background and an `UILabel`) right below the `UINavigationController` so that when my table scrolls, the tooltip will NOT move along with it. Is there any way do accomplish this without using XIB files and just storyboard?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but couldn't you just build the image & label view into the storyboard above the tableview so that the two are completely separate?

Answer (score 0):

Might not exactly be what you wanted, but if you want a UITableViewcontroller and setting things up using only storyboards:

the easiest way  would probably be to either use the navigationbar (make it bigger by choosing "with prompt") or the toolbar at the bottom, both in the attributes inspector of your TableViewController

or (depending on which functionalities you need) you could simply drag out a ViewController and put a TableView inside, then customize everything as you want

Comment: Not really what I was looking for. I have multiple tableview that push each other, and I want to enable tooltips for only some of them.

Comment: you can set the navigationbar "prompt" for each VC individually, won't do anything to the other's and animate in and out automatically when pushing around

Comment: I just redid everything from UIViewControllers instead of UITableViewControllers in storyboard and individually set the delegate and datasource of all the tableviews to the VC; works fine